# Application_AcquireRequestState() fires multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, globalization, httpcontext, cultureinfo

I use this following method in mvc3 application:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)this.Session["Culture"];

                if (ci == null)
                {
                    string langName = "az";
                    ci = new CultureInfo(langName);
                    this.Session["Culture"] = ci;
                }

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
            }
        }
```

Why is this method called many times?

And when site opens in new browser in other PC, site resources not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your page have multiple elements (images, scripts, etc.) resulting in multiple HTTP Get requests? If so, this will fire once for each.

Comment: I do not understand you well.. There are images, scripts, in my pages. When I start application, that method fires many times, 1 time   HttpContext.Current.Session is null, next time is not null, so, that is repeated..

Comment: The browser software application is making multiple HTTP Get or Post requests while rendering the page (or "opening the site"). `Application_AcquireRequestState` gets called once for each HTTP Get or Post request.

Comment: Can I use CultureInfo, set site language without using  Application_AcquireRequestState() method, for examle, write its code into Application_Start() ??